# How to add email links in datagridview using C#.net?

Tags: c#, datagridview, email

Can anyone tell me how to add email links to a particular column contatining email addresses.
For instance, i have a database containig details of employees or customers in a gridview populated from excel sheet. One of the Columns containing the email address of each customer respectively is displayed in the gridview.. All i want here is to by clicking the particular email id of a person, the compose page of Mail should open with the selected email id in the recipient's textbox.

Comment: On question quality: Please don't add "thank you notes" (upvote/accept/comment instead) and signature (you have user name for it). If it is urgent - pay someone instead of asking here, adding "urgent", using all caps and similar will not get your question answered faster.

Comment: alryt.. im sry i wont do it.. im new here...

Comment: Try this link, I hope it will help you. link- http://abhijitjana.net/2010/07/27/how-to-pass-multiple-values-using-gridview-hyperlinkfield/  can you share your code

Comment: That was quick... but the link gives me solution to asp.net.. i need it in c#.net.. can you help me with that?

Answer (score 3):

Add a DataGridViewLinkColumn and bind it to the email address column of your datasource.  In your DataGridView_CellClick event add the following code:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) // Assuming it's the first column
{
    Process.Start("mailto:" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
}
```

You can call Process.Start("mailto:test@test.com"); and it should launch your default mail client.

Answer (score 1):

On the cellclick event of the DGV, check if the columnindex is of the email column,
If u want to use your default mail client, use, Adam's solution with the email value obtained from the cell,
or if your application has it's own compose page, pass the value as a property or something.
Easy solutions are the best.